MaskRCNN in pytorch gives different loss everytime
I am doing instance segmentation using maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2. I have only class in the training dataset but each image can have up 1000 instances of the single class.
I am running all my codes on kaggle notebook.
I set seed using this function
def seed_everything(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)  
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False  

The loss is perfectly reproducible if I use cpu but in gpu the loss is different everytime I run the training loop
But the first epoch loss is same. I am only using single image to train the model to see if everything works or not and reproducible
The model
def get_model():
    seed_everything(CFG.seed)
    model = maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn_v2(weights='DEFAULT')
    seed_everything(CFG.seed)
    
    class_names = ['field', "background"]
    # Get the number of input features for the classifier
    in_features_box = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    in_features_mask = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.in_channels
    # Get the numbner of output channels for the Mask Predictor
    dim_reduced = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.out_channels
    # Replace the box predictor
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_channels=in_features_box, num_classes=len(class_names))
    # Replace the mask predictor
    model.roi_heads.mask_predictor = MaskRCNNPredictor(in_channels=in_features_mask, dim_reduced=dim_reduced, num_classes=len(class_names))
    
    return model.to(CFG.device)

The training loop
model = get_model()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
no_epochs = 10
epoch_loss = []
model.train()
for epoch_no in tqdm(range(1, no_epochs+1)):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    losses = model(input_batch, targets)
    loss = sum([loss for loss in losses.values()]) 
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(f"Epoch no: {epoch_no} | loss: {loss.item():.4f}")
    epoch_loss.append(loss.item())

After running the model first time the losses look like this
Epoch no: 1 | loss: 6.6777
Epoch no: 2 | loss: 8.2722
Epoch no: 3 | loss: 3.3449
Epoch no: 4 | loss: 2.6268
Epoch no: 5 | loss: 2.5746
Epoch no: 6 | loss: 2.2247
Epoch no: 7 | loss: 2.2633
Epoch no: 8 | loss: 2.3275
Epoch no: 9 | loss: 2.1480
Epoch no: 10 | loss: 2.0851

If I run the training loop again the losses are
Epoch no: 1 | loss: 6.6777
Epoch no: 2 | loss: 8.2743
Epoch no: 3 | loss: 3.4022
Epoch no: 4 | loss: 2.6555
Epoch no: 5 | loss: 2.6238
Epoch no: 6 | loss: 2.2365
Epoch no: 7 | loss: 2.1556
Epoch no: 8 | loss: 2.1003
Epoch no: 9 | loss: 2.1026
Epoch no: 10 | loss: 2.0324

The first loss is always same.But from the second epoch it starts to get different
Secondly
If I create a new model with this code
model = get_model()

then pass the code below two times
losses = model(input_batch, targets)
loss = sum([loss for loss in losses.values()]) 
print(loss.item())

it gives two different loss value
First time loss:  6.677738666534424
Second time loss:  7.194179534912109

I do not get how this is possible since I did not change any weights the model should not have changed.
I have tried using torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True) but If I do this my gpu run out of memory.  I have seen some topics regarding this issues none of them has worked for me.
What should I do?
I want the model to reproducible so that I can tune the hyper parameters and choose the best ones. My dataset only has 50 train images

This is an expected behavior, as of right now it is not entirely possible to run perfectly deterministic operations on the GPU.
See this answer for more information : How to handle non-determinism when training on a GPU?
Basically, some operations on the GPU are non deterministic because of multi threading.
Your losses are still quite similar, it should suffice for your hyper-parameter tuning.
